# How do I use Applescript to select a specific file in the Project Pane of a BBEdit window? SOLVED

Tags: applescript, bbedit

**SOLVED -- at end!**

How do I use Applescript to select a specific file in the Project Pane of a BBEdit window?

When I open BBEdit, without AppleScript, my Project opens up, with the Project file list in the left Pane just like it should.

**With AppleScript**, I wish to

1. select a specific file in this Pane and then
2. select "Preview in BBEdit" under its "Markup" Menu.

The challenge right now is to use AppleScript for #1. I have tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate

    set theFile to "compiled_corona_virus.html"

    select theFile
end tell
```

I get this error:

```
error "BBEdit got an error: \"compiled_corona_virus.html\" doesn’t understand the “select” message." number -1708 from "compiled_corona_virus.html"
```

I have definitely looked at BBEdit's AppleScript Dictionary which reads:

```
select v : Select the specified object
select [specifier] : the object to select
```

For what it's worth, I have tried this Script within Apple's Script Editor:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate

    tell application "Finder" to set theFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:johnlove:Sites:www.lovetoteach.dev:Web_Site_Storage:lovesongforever.com:coronavirus:compiled_corona_virus.html"

    select theFile
end tell
```

Identical select error?

I did also try to use

```
open theFile
```

and BBEdit did open it and show the opened theFile in the right-most Pane, but **without** selecting this file in the left-most Project Pane.

**SOLVED by Rich Siegel at barebones.com**

Rich is the author of the Pearl of Wisdom "Someday I will look back on all of this and laugh .. until they sedate me!"

```
on setAutoRevealSelectedDocumentInProjectList()

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "defaults write com.barebones.bbedit AutoRevealSelectedDocumentInProjectList -bool YES "
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell

end setAutoRevealSelectedDocumentInProjectList
```

Rich patiently teaches us that the leftmost Pane of BBEdit's window, consists of two separate parts:

```
1) the Project's files on top
2) Currently Open Documents at the bottom
```

If you develop an AppleScript that opens a file via the open(name) command, BBEdit will open it and show it highlighted at the bottom under "Currently Open Documents".

HOWEVER, this does not change the Project file selected on top.

SO, to do that, the programmer must invoke Terminal with:

```
setAutoRevealSelectedDocumentInProjectList()
```

THANK YOU, Rich!!

Comment: In BBEdit's dictionary, there are a handful of 'project' terms, e.g. project window, project item, etc…. Within the project window, 'selected items' is read-only — so you can determine which items are selected but cannot select them. Also, BBEdit is a recordable app so you can start recording a script and then open a project and a text file and the commands will be created in the script. This is useful for getting syntax, such as for opening a file.

Comment: Your statement "Within the project window, 'selected items' is read-only" is the big clue ... and I really thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use "open" instead of "select". If the file is already open, BBEdit will select it. If the file isn't already open, BBEdit will open it and then select it. (Whether you're using a hardcoded path, or not, is irrelevant, as long as the file you're asking BBEdit to open actually exists.)

The "open" command refers a reference to the document just opened.

The "select" verb is not appropriate for use on files; it will only work on "document" objects.

This (or something like it) will do what you want:

```
tell app "BBEdit"
    set openedDocument to (open POSIX file "/path/to/some/file.txt") -- substitute your actual file path here
    select openedDocument
end tell
```

In addition: if you are working in a project document, the selection in the "Projects" section does not automatically change to reflect the active document. (The selection in the "Currently Open Documents" section always does.)

There is an expert preference which controls this behavior. Cribbing from the Expert Preferences help:

> BBEdit will not automatically reveal documents in the project list when you select them; View => Reveal in Project List works for this purpose. If you want automatic revealing:
>
> `defaults write com.barebones.bbedit AutoRevealSelectedDocumentInProjectList -bool YES`

Comment: opens the doc, but doesn't select the doc's name in the leftmost Project Pane.  Please look at my comment above "Something very interesting" etc.

Comment: If you are working in a project document, the selection in the "Projects" section does not automatically change to reflect the active document. (The selection in the "Currently Open Documents" section always does.)

Comment: And I updated my OP with your correct answer. THANKS A MILLION TIMES OVER!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be more useful for you if you didn't have to hardcode the file location in the script, and instead ask for the location of the file at the time you run it?

```
set theFile to choose file

tell application "BBEdit"
    open theFile
end tell
```

When I use that code, Bbedit opens the file and has it selected in the left hand pane.

Comment: Oh, how I wish your idea worked ... didn't have any file in the left Pane selected at the beginning ... then ran your script ... opened the correct file in the right Pane, but nothing was selected in the left Pane

Comment: Something very interesting ... when I open a file in BBEdit, followed by: tell application "BBEdit" to select text document 1 of project window 1, the value = text document "compiled_corona_virus.html" of application "BBEdit". This is the correct value. But, this file listed in the Project Pane on the left side of the BBEdit window is NOT selected. Most confusing! Is the problem that this file list in the Project Window read only? I have changed that read only to FALSE, but still no selection of the file in the Project Window.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you are trying to accomplish by having that document selected in the project pane, it would help some of us come up with a solution for you. Right now I am a little hazy as to why it is important for it to be selected in the project pane if the document is open and is the front document.

Comment: With AppleScript, 1) tell application “BBEdit” to open(fileName) opens up file on right. 2) tell application "BBEdit" to select text document 1 of project window 1, does have the correct file name yet does not select it on left. The old selection stays, thus selection on left doesn’t match display on right.

Comment: Problem solved! by Rich Siegel of barebones.com  Edited the OP to reflect Rich's solution